# jQuery code optimization possible?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I am using jQuery to custom style the default select box. In addition to hiding it and overlaying with a div element I have added a hover function. Basically it works, although I haven't tested it yet in all major browsers and I will probably have to build in a fallback for IE6 (who is still using it?).

Since I am just a beginner, I was wondering if this code can be optimized in any way. Thanks!

```
$("select").each(function(){
   $(this).wrap('<div class="sbox"/>');
   $(this).after("<span class='sboxtext'></span><span class='sboxarrow'></span>");
   $(".sbox").hover( function (e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('sbox-over');
     $(this).find("span.sboxarrow").toggleClass('sboxarrow-over');
   });
   var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
   $(this).next(".sboxtext").text(val);
   $(this).change(function(){
     var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
     $(this).next(".sboxtext").text(val);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `each` method, jQuery iterates through the selected elements behind the scenes. If you are using jQuery 1.9-, your code also works in older versions of IE.

```
$("select").wrap('<div class="sbox"/>')
           .after("<span class='sboxtext'></span><span class='sboxarrow'></span>")
           .parent()
           .hover(function() {
               $(this).toggleClass('sbox-over')
                      .find(".sboxarrow")
                      .toggleClass('sboxarrow-over');
           }).end()
           .change(function() {
               var $this = $(this),
                   val = $this.children("option:selected").text();
               $this.next().text(val);
           }).change();
```

- Cache the objects
- Use the chainability that jQuery provides

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! Not the reputation to vote yet, but for what it's worth +10 in my book :)

Answer (score 0):

dom manipulation is very expensive in loops, so you must detach the element.

```
var selectbox = $("select").detach();
```

and perform operations on selectbox.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I will need to dive into this. "detach()" has been bookmarked.